# ajaxToolkid: TabContainer: when click the tabs a box is displaying

Tags: ajax, tabs

I am using ajaxToolkid TabContainer with TabPanels and is working as well, but when i click on the tabs is displaying a box.

what is displaying:
[tabs displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iVqa.png)
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i have found the solution.

The problem was at the headertemplate which was the below:

```
<headertemplate> TabPanel1 
  <style type ="text/css">     
    .ajax__tab_xp.ajax__tab_tab {
    height: 300px;
    min-height: 300px;
}
  </style> 
</headertemplate>
```

I have erased it and then i had this problem:
[Ajax Tabcontainer Header cuts off in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22947327/ajax-tabcontainer-header-cuts-off-in-chrome)
and i solved it with the help of above link.